Talend 8.0.1 - Insert POINT data type into postgresql from csv file
I'm using Talend Open Studio 8.0.1 and I'm trying to import data from a csv file into a postgresql database.
I'll provide a simplified example of my specific issue :
My test.csv file is as below :
id,lon_lat
1,"(450360.648, 122484.406)"
2,"(450384.431, 122363.579)"
I'm trying to just insert this into a postgresql table with the same columns :
CREATE TABLE ntw.nodes (
id int8 NOT NULL,
lon_lat point NULL,
CONSTRAINT nodes_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
My issue is with the lon_lat field, as I parse is as String in talend (talend does not have a point type), and when trying to insert it into my database with tPostgresqlOutput component, I get this error message :
ERROR: column "lon_lat" is of type point but expression is of type character varying
Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
I do not know how to deal with this.
Additional info :

I would prefer not to use tPostgresqlRow component as it does not offer batch insert
I have tried with different data type on talend without success
The query in this error message work if I just execute it (for example using dbeaver)
I think the way to do it is to use the Additional columns to replace lon_lat with an SQL expression that would cat the value of lon_lat as a point but I was not able to get the syntax right, nor did I find instruction that helped on the net

EDIT : question has been answered by Zegarek. Apply the same method as in the post he links but with "?::point"

It looks like you can add a ::point cast in "Advanced Settings" tab on your "tPostgresqlOutput" component.

@Zegarek Yes, that was it, thanks!
